# workflow for SharePoint list and CRM

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, dynamics-crm

Can I use one workflow for both Microsoft Dynamics CRM and SharePoint 2013 list? Any Idea

Comment: Is it a SharePoint on-premises list? Your tag says SharePoint-online but the question says sp2013. If you are looking for SP online list you will find the detailed answer below.

Comment: @Venkat My environment is SharePoint 2013. I made correction. Thanks

Comment: `Microsoft Dynamic CRM` is also on-premises?

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: Did you ever try SharePoint workflow HTTP Web Call action? I have not worked with Dynamic CRM. But `HTTP Web Call` action is intended to interact with different systems using REST API

Comment: Not yet. If you have the link let me look at. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60974/discussion-between-venkat-konjeti-and-sara).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with Microsoft Dynamics and SharePoint lists at a time using Microsoft Flows in Sharepoint online.

There are out of the box flow templates to understand how it works.

[image]

You can also achieve multiple business cases using custom flows without compromising with security Example cases as follows

1. Update records in Dynamics when an item inserted/updated/deleted from SharePoint.
2. Update SharePoint when an item inserted/updated/deleted from Dynamics.
3. You can also integrate these systems with other cloud systems also.

These very simple and easy to configure in minutes without writing a single line of code.

[Learn Microsoft Flows](https://flow.microsoft.com/)